# How to use django annotate to compare current date with other date in models

Tags: django, django-models

I want to get the days between the current time and another date.
Here is the command what I used:

```
employees = Employee.objects.annotate(
        duration=ExpressionWrapper(datetime.now().date() - F('start_working_date'), output_field=DurationField())
        )
```

But the result I got( employee.duration) is 0.

```
for employee in employees:
    employee.duration
```

And here is my models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start_working_date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use **F** class to compare the time you wanted with one of the fields (start_working_date) of the model.

two tips:
1-for **now** time its better to use django timezone

2-you should use **.date()** method of **now** to be able to compare it with your start_working_date

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.utils import timezone    

employees = Employee.objects.annotate(
   duration=timezone.now().date() - F('start_working_date')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this `__range`

```
date_range = [from_date, to_date ]
emp = Employee.objects.filter(start_working_date__range=date_range)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) to pass and use a value in a query expression

```
from datetime import date
from django.db.models import F, Value

employees = Employee.objects.annotate(
    duration=Value(date.today()) - F('start_working_date')
)
```

Comment: But I still got the same result.

Comment: When I used this, I got this error:
But I got this error:
(Pdb) employee_test = Employee.objects.annotate(duration=Value(date.day()) - F('start_working_date'))
*** TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable